# UITableView the last cell in a section appears a separator

Tags: uitableview

I set my tableview's separatorStyle like below:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

But my last custom cell in 0 section have a separator:

[the last cell appears separator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDdWD.png)

As you see the last cell in second section did not have a separator.
Why the last cell in first section have one?
I reveal into the view hierarchy as below shows, WYRealNameInfoCell is the last cell appears separator, it have two Separators!

[the view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9iGs.png)

If I add codes in the cell's implementation like below:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
// Initialization code
for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
    if (view != self.contentView) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

}

There will only one _UITableViewCellSeparatorView.

Why does it appears separator, and how to avoid such issues?

Comment: By the way, only the WYRealNameInfoCell is custom cell

Comment: You are using custom cell, so you can use label with 1px height and stretch upto the tableview width. Before that set seperator style to none. it will show seperator line in all rows.

Comment: @karthik I don't want all the cells show seperator. I just want to know why the last cell shows a seperator